# Get client system information in LTSP

Tags: system, ltsp, info

I'm trying to get the system information of clients booted via LTSP to a Ubuntu 10.04 server. Any time I try any system info commands (example lspci | grep VGA) it returns back the server information, not the client.

Is there a way to see the client information in LTSP? Local apps perhaps? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a program called 'epoptes' and then reboot the clients. The clients will then show up in detected clients within the server side app and you can right client on each and go to 'Information' This will give you a summary of hardware on each client.